# Record my Screen in ADM with Pixel

Tags: android, adb, video-recording

I want to record a short video of my app running. I run Android Device Monitor (ADM) on my hardware Pixel device and I can only find the 'screenshot' icon which works fine.

I've checked all over stack overflow and followed the advice and prerequisites at https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-video.html
.

No record icon or menu option anywhere for it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can start to write a video with this command in your terminal:

```
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/demo.mp4
```

Then you can stop to write a video when pressing `Ctrl`+`C`

Later you can pull it with `adb  pull /sdcard/demo.mp4 ~/`

More details you can find here:

- [adb commands](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html)
- [Recording a Video from the Screen via Android Monitor](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-video.html#video)

Comment: Brilliant! But is there a menu option / icon I'm simply missing or is using the terminal the only way?

Comment: @Xarsiss I use the terminal, it's fast and easy, although I'm not a fan of the command line.